# Meaning of Error Squiggles in VSCode Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My java code has these error squiggles. What do they mean and how do I disable them?

[image: Error Squiggles Java]

Mouse Over Drop Down 1

[image]

Mouse Over Drop Down 2

[image]

What do these mean? What does the software suggest me to do?

PS: I'm a complete newb

Comment: What happens if you hover over them with your mouse?

Comment: They are not errors, by the way, only suggestions.

Comment: To know why it's telling you that: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-106 and https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1197.

Comment: I don't know what rule you're "breaking" with that last line but I guess it's suggesting you should use a constant rather than a literal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints, no error. For proposing code changes, and SonarLint: code style warnings.

Here it suggests (wrongly so) to replace System.out by a shorter final PrintWriter, say `out`, so you need only to use `out.println(...)`. That is not normally done.

But a similar rule states that one should use a Logger instead.

For the main: `new Hello().execute();` and then in a separate non-static method (`execute`) do the code you wrote in `main`.

---

***SonarLint:*** code style checker, named after the C *lint* tool to find "[lint](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/englisch/lint)" in the code, dubious code pieces, like unitialized variables, dangerous lossy conversions and such.

---

Writing to System.out (the console) is not good style in a web server or a GUI desktop application, hence the advice is to use a Logger for logging interesting information, possibly to the console, but also possibly to a log file.

You should especially as a beginner not disable the linting extension.
Ignore the squiggles, only from time to time look at them.
One can also disable specific SonarLint rules one finds dumb.

Comment: I am a beginner and did nit understand most off what you said (like loggers). Disabling the linting extension worked. Thanks!

Comment: A developer should ask ones entire life, only so we can understand business and new information technologies.

Comment: I have added a bit of explanation, it looked you had already some background. In C one would write `String args[]` which is a C compatible syntax, but in java one normally keeps the type together: `String[] args`.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the extension "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" . This was the extension that did the code linting. Now the squiggles are gone.